# Firestore rules not working for userId

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having a simple collection users, document id is using the uid with name string
[image]

I'm using angularfire2 to connect to the collection

```
this.users = afs.collection<User>('users').valueChanges();
```

I'm using firebase authentication. When displaying the user id, I get 4NxoeUeB4OXverhHhiw86eKl0Sj1 which match with the user document.

```
this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => console.log(auth.uid));
```

I'm trying to add rules for the collection. If I use the rules below, I get error Missing or insufficient permissions.

```
`service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}`
```

If I change the rule to request.auth != null the data is shown.

```
`service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}`
```

What could I have done wrong? I'm also trying a few different rules eg. `resource.data.name != null`. It is also not working.

I am testing the rule. The end result I want a readers array field and writers array field so I can try something like `request.auth.uid in resource.data.readers` to control access to the document

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to get `/users/*` but you only have access to `/users/{yourid}`.

You should only retrieve data you have access to, so you need to filter your query even if you actually only have one document.

```js
// either by adding a field in your doc
afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('id', '==', auth.uid))

// or by getting the document directly
afs.collection('users').doc(auth.uid)
```

> When performing a rules check on a query, Cloud Firestore Security
>   Rules will check to ensure that the user has access to **all results**
>   before executing the query. If a query could return results a user
>   doesn't have access to, the entire query fails and Firestore returns
>   an error.

Source : https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/security/secure-data#shallow_queries

Comment: Thanks for the answer Remi, I guess I understand what is needed for the Rules and query better now. Firestore query would be really great if can implement the access control like Lotus Notes. For example, if I query standard users collection, it will only return the document that I have access to. Don't need to specifically build a query to documents that I have access.

Comment: WOW I just spent hours trying to figure this out!  maddening.  I expected my client could just ask "give me all the docs in this collection that I have access to" and the server would only return those that match the rules... not that I have to build the exact where clause to match the rules ahead of time.  grrr...