# Security Rules for Admin Users and Creators

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I can't understand exactly how it work to create my rules for Firestore.

So far what I've tried with the help from the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions?authuser=1),

1. I created a document called users with a user that have my UID.
2. Then I created a field named admin
3. I've set it to true.

Now my rule look like this :

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /trainings/{$tId} {
            allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true
        }
    }
}
```

I fetch my data in javascript

```
this._db
    .collection('/trainings')
    .get()
    .then(itemsColl => itemsColl)
```

That don't work. My next step will be to add a created_by field with the UID on each of my training to get the creator uid stored and add a rule so they can read/write them training stuff.

Someone can help me getting that first rule working and tell me if my next step look in the right way ?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why the rules won't work. Maybe it'll be easier to help if you share the code that you're using to read/write this data.

Comment: I added my fetch, don't think it add a lot, but if that can help you :)

Comment: You're trying to read the entire collection, but you only grant access to specific documents. You need to make sure that what you read does not exceed what your rules allow, i.e. your query should also ensure it only reads docs it is an admin on. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query (the first query on that page is what you're trying to do here as far as I can see). Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46859953/firestore-rules-not-working-for-userid/46863064#46863064, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50527478/209103